# jqGrid in a Google maps InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jqgrid

I am trying to have jqGrid inside the InfoWindow of Google maps but somehow I can't make it work.

I have the following code:

```
function infoClosure(map, marker, val) {
    return function() {
        content = [];

        content.push('<div class="infowin">');
        content.push('<table id="list1"></table>');
        content.push('<div id="pager1"></div>');
        content.push('<script type="text/javascript">');
        content.push('jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({');
        content.push('url:"getdata.php?lat=' + val.lat + '&long=' + val.long + '",');
        content.push('datatype: "xml",');
        content.push('colNames:["Project id","Project name"],');
        content.push('colModel:[');
        content.push('{name:"projectID",index:"projectID", width:75}');
        content.push('],');
        content.push('rowNum:10,');
        content.push('autowidth: true,');
        content.push('rowList:[10,20,30],');
        content.push('pager: "#pager1",');
        content.push('sortname: "id",');
        content.push('viewrecords: true,');
        content.push('sortorder: "desc",');
        content.push('caption:"Current projects"');
        content.push('});');
        content.push('jQuery("#list1").jqGrid("navGrid","#pager1",{edit:false,add:false,del:false});');
        content.push('</script>');

        infoWindow.setContent(content.join(''));
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
}
```

We are using `content.push` to pass the java scripts bits of jqGrid to the info window but such code make the google map to no show.

Any idea how to make it work?

Regards,
Carlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I miss definition of the second column ("Project name") in `colModel` of your code. Moreover you have `sortname: "id"` instead of probably `sortname: "projectID"`. I recommend you include additionally `gridview: true` option too.

The next problem is that the `<div class="infowin">` will be not closed. The HTML fragment which you use is

```html
<div class="infowin">
    <table id="list1"></table>
    <div id="pager1"></div>
??? where is </div> ???
```

What I would recommend you to do additionally is to debug the grid first *without* creating the code dynamically. I mean that you can create *static* `<div class="infowin"><table id="list1"></table><div id="pager1"></div></div>` create jqGrid also in the same way like one do it typically. Only after the code will work you can include one line of code which **move** the grid inside of `infoWindow` with respect of `infoWindow.setContent`:

```
infoWindow.setContent($("#list1").closest(".infowin")[0]); // move div over grid
```

Comment: Hi, I did what you said: 1) added the missing </div> 2) I tested the grid code outside the infoWindow, 3) Moved the working grid code dinamically using content.push(''); Like: content.push('<script type="text/javascript">'); .... content.push('</script>'); But Now I get big error message like: '); content.push('
'); content.push('
'); content.push('
'); content.push('
'); infoWindow.setContent(content.join('')); infoWindow.open(map, marker); } } function codeAddress() { $(document).ready(function() ..... infoClosure(map, marker, val) ); }); }); }); } codeAddress(); };

Comment: @QLands: I think there are misunderstanding. I suggested **don't use any array of strings and not to use** `infoWindow.setContent(content.join(''));`. If you have some static div (`<div class="infowin">...here is the grid...</div>`) you can *move* the working grid with respect of `infoWindow.setContent($("#list1").closest(".infowin")[0]); infoWindow.open(map, marker);` instead. If you need to have grid non-visible for some time you can call `jQuery.hide()` on the div and call `jQuery.hide()` on the div when it should be seen.

Comment: Hi, I did what you indicated and I make it work!... Just one more thing... when I click on a map market shows the grid properly but once I close the infoWindow the grid does not work again with another marker. Maybe I need to move the "infowin" back to where it was... But how can I do that?  Many many thanks!

Comment: @QLands: You are welcome! You can for example use some jQuery methods like `jQuery.insert`, `jQuery.append` and so on to *move* the div one more time before closing the map. In the case you need register some event handler which will be called *before* closing the map. Alternatively you can *recreate* the grid. You need just create new `<div class="infowin">...</div>` and use `jQuery.html` or `jQuery.insert` to place it on the HTML page and call `jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({...})`. So you don't need to create `<script>` part and just call your existing code.

Comment: @QLands: I have seen, that you not used your voting right till now. You have right to vote up any question or answer. You can do this about **30 times per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). Voting is important because it will be used by searching engine. So if you find some helpful answer or question you should vote it up. Accepting of answers is not so important for the searching engine. You need just click "Up" arrows on the left part of the question/answer. So if you want help other people to find helpful information you should use your right to vote.

Comment: @QLands: By the way I explained you about voting only because it's really important feature of the stackoverflow (and not to improve my reputation). You can for example goes trough old answers which you get and vote all helpful, but in general one should use voting for *any other good answers (or questions)* which you will find in the future. Best wishes for you!

Comment: Hi, I added a <div class="infocont">...</div> as container to infowin. Also I have a event handler before close with the code $(".infowin").prependTo(".infocont");
   $(".infowin").hide();  to try to move the div back, but the second time the infowindow loads it fail to move the grid to the infowindow ... Thanks

Comment: @QLands: I'm afraid, I couldn't find the reason of the problem, which you described, without have seen the JavaScript code and HTML code. Moreover I described you above *the second way* to recreate the grid at the second time. See above usage of `jQuery.insert` with `<div class="infowin">...</div>` and executing the same code which contains `jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({...})`.

Comment: Hi, Success!!! with jQuery.insert and moved the jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({...}) to a function. Thank you very much.

Comment: @QLands: You are welcome! I'm glad to hear that the problem is full solved now.